# Redirect https to http on non-https server using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My server isn't set up for HTTPS, however some users are still browsing using HTTPS in the URL.  This is preventing my chat application from working properly.

I need to redirect the chat pages from HTTPS to HTTP by changing the htaccess file.  The pages have the URLs /chat, /chat/index and chat/text.

I've tried the following but can't seem to get it to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^chat$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^chat/index$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^chat/text$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have HTTPS on your server then don't be selective, redirect everything to HTTP

```
# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't redirect **https** to **http** if you don't have ssl certificate or ssl isn't enabled on your server. You will get an ssl certificate error if you don't have the ssl certificate. You need to buy an ssl certificate for your domain in order to redirect https to http.

After getting a valid ssl certificate , you may use the following rule to redirect **https://example.com/chat** to **http://example.com/chat**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^chat http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following finally solved problem for me:

Redirecting all **https** and/OR **www** requests to **non-https** and **non-www** and all its subdirectories.

**https://example.com/**            to  **http://example.com/**

**https://www.example.com/**   to  **http://example.com/**

**http://www.example.com/**     to  **http://example.com/**

added to my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Mind you, **NOT escaping** the **"."** with **"\."** in the RewriteCond

Worked on my shared hosting (escaping the "." with "\." did not work on my hosting, to my surprise)